# On an average, how many more leads do organizations have in their Marketo instances v/s their Salesforce instances?

Tags: data-synchronization, marketing-cloud

This question is directed at organizations with a Marketo-Salesforce [or similar Marketing Automation service - Salesforce] integration set up.

What is the average number of leads you have in your Marketo instance v/s your Salesforce instance?

I'm guessing there are quite a few leads in Marketo that never hit the lead score threshold required for them to sync down to Salesforce. I wanted an estimate of the same.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Marketo

Comment: This question is actually about Salesforce's integration with Marketo. I'd think that makes it relevant to both Salesforce and Marketo fora, right?

Comment: It's not about how to use the product. And, as such, it is not the kind of question that this community is set up to handle. Thank you for your enthusiasm, though.

Comment: Is there a list of guidelines for what kind of questions are valid for this community?

As a Salesforce developer who is considering integrating with Marketo, I find this question quite relevant to my architectural considerations. I'd imagine some other Salesforce developers would concur.

Comment: I've read the [help center](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) doc and the [don't ask](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) doc. 

Could you please let me know which rule this question violates? I believe it falls under 'subjective' but 'invites sharing experiences over opinions' about Salesforce's integrations. This question also does have a 'specific answer' as required in the help center doc.

Thanks for being responsive.

Comment: Reopening this for now - we'll see how the answers stack up.

Comment: I'm curious about this as well...  the best practices around what leads show up in salesforce vs marketo...

Answer (score 2):

As you would expect, the number of leads sent to Salesforce is lower than the number of leads in Marketo. That said, the percentage sent to Salesforce from Marketo varies by company. It depends on the scoring threshold set up within the company's Marketo instance.

For specific numbers, I would recommend asking in the Marketo user group forum:
https://www.linkedin.com/groups/Marketo-User-Group-San-Francisco-3163175/about